# Libreoffice: Fill down without affecting format

Tags: libreoffice-calc

If I fill cells in libreoffice by dragging on the small black rectangle (on the bottom right corner of a cell), it doesn't only fill the formula (which was my intention) but also the format (font, background color, etc). How can I fill the formula without filling the format?

I know that I can copy the formula, select the cell range where the formula should be filled in and then paste it via "paste special" (selecting only formulas). But there are much more steps involved compared to just dragging down for example.

So what would be the simplest solution to my problem? Is it possible to configure a modifier key, which toggles if the format is filled or not when dragging?

Answer (score 3):

Found the soultion from this old [thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=37717):

> - Select the range beginning from A10 to A1 (A1 is active cell)
> - Press F2
> - Delete the last character ( ← backspace)
> - Enter the character you have deleted
> - Press Alt+Enter